# RegexExtract multiple values from a single row from an array

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of products

```
Product
Vegetable
Soup
Meat
Fish
```

I have a list of items:

```
Item
Fish and Vegetable Soup
meat soup
Fish and Vegetable
```

now i want to extract each match from above via a regex function

I thought it would be as as simple as

```
{=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,TEXTJOIN('|', TRUE,PRODUCTS!A2:A))}
```

however this returns none or just the first match in my list.

target output:

```
Item                    |Expected Output
Fish and Vegetable Soup |Fish, Vegetable, Soup
meat soup               |Meat, Soup
Fish and Vegetable      |Fish, Vegetable
```

demo sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lplluXxtdyS-JvwwcEmCZGZ1sYoi4-49kDsUbx6D3gc/edit?usp=sharing)

given that D2 is the text I want to use the expression on, and A2:A is my list of products.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

Short Version:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(D4," ",True),TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,A2:A)),"")))`

as the `regexextract` function ends after the first match we need to do the following to make it iterate over my row.

first we use `split` and split each item in each cell by whitespace `' '`

`=split(A2, " ")`

which gives us

[image: Split Array]

We wrap this in an `ArrayFormula` which according to google's helper function :

> Enables the display of values returned from an array formula into
>   multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with
>   arrays

next step is to use the `regextract` function, with the help of the `ArrayFormula` lets us match each element returned from the split

`=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B2, " "),TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, A2:A)`

`textjoin` returns a single cell with values seperated by our chosen delimiter `|` in some programming languages `|` is an OR statement which gives us.

[image]

to top it off, we use an `IFERROR` statement to ignore the `#NAs` we don't care about those. and a further `TEXTJOIN` to bring it all in one cell sepeareted by comma.

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(D2," ",True),TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,A2:A)),"")))`

[image]